# Push notifications not being received on iPhone( ios 8.3) devices while it is working fine on all iPad iOS versions including iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using Push Notification in my app. It works fine on all iPad iOS versions including iOS 8.3 but strangely on iPhones it is not being received. I have tested on iPhone 5C having iOS 8.3 and iPhone 5S having iOS 8.3. Though Push notification events are being fired from these two iPhones but they are not being received !!

iPhone is generating device token for registration when clicking on "OK" button of push notification alert. I am really at loss to understand as to what is the problem. I have also tried creating new set of certificates, provisioning profiles but the problem is still the same. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My codes are as follow

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
.....
    [self registerForRemoteNotification];

.....
    return YES;
}


- (void)registerForRemoteNotification
{
    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"])
    {
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"])
    {
    }

}

#endif


- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {

.....
}



- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

  ......
}
```

So please solve my problem.

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

" Push notification events are being fired from these two iPhones ". What does this mean? Push notifications don't originate on the iPhone. I presume that is just a typo and you meant push events are being fired to the two iPhone.

The first thing is to double check that you are using the correct push token, and when sending to the iPhones you are actually using their push tokens and not the iPad push token.

If that is ok then are these foreground pushes or background pushes? If they are background pushes then try plugging the iPhones into a power supply when you are sending the push and see if they are received then.